# How do you fix Terraform unsupported attribute "ses_smtp_password" after upgrading to 0.13?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

After upgrading I was getting messages like the following when running a `terraform plan`:

```
Error: Invalid resource instance data in state

  on iam_server_backup.tf line 4:
   4: resource "aws_iam_access_key" "backup" {

Instance aws_iam_access_key.backup data could not be decoded from
the state: unsupported attribute "ses_smtp_password".
```

The way I fixed it was by removing the state (`terraform state rm aws_iam_access_key.backup`). However, that created new access keys when I ran `terraform apply`, which was time-consuming because I had to change all my access keys in all my apps. Is there a better way to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you use / specify the `ses_smtp_password` anywhere?

Comment: No, it wasn't in my config anywhere.

Answer (score 18):

I encountered this same `unsupported attribute "ses_smtp_password"` issue when I updated my aws terraform provider, and was able to fix it by manually downloading and modifying the state.

```
terraform state pull > state.json
```

now edit `state.json` and

- remove any line with `ses_smtp_password`
- increment the `serial` attribute (ex `"serial": 21,` -> `"serial": 22,`)
- save

```
terraform state push state.json
terraform plan # should work again
```

optional, but makes it so you can't accidentally commit your state file

```
rm state.json
```

Comment: You can avoid having to push your state after each change by:

- Changing your states save location to local (typically just comment out the `backend{}` block)
- Running `terraform init -migrate-state` to migrate the remote state to a local .tfstate file
- Back up the resulting .tfstate file just in case
- Edit the .tfstate file as required until your state is fixed
- Revert any code state save location changes
- Running `terraform init -migrate-state` to migrate the local state back to remote

Comment: I had this problem with a suddenly-removed attribute in the auth0 Terraform provider.  The attribute was `custom_login_page_preview`.  I used jq to delete those entries in a repeatable way.

```
cat state-.json | jq 'del(.resources[].instances[].attributes.custom_login_page_preview)' > state-no-custom_login_page_preview.json
```

I also provided some AI with the full path to on instance of the attribute and got the same query i'd come up with, wrapped in `del()`.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I too just faced this issue and wanted to provide a solution that does not require mucking with states.

The solution to this is to upgrade the AWS provider to ~> 3.0 before upgrading to terraform 0.13. This caused the `ses_smtp_password` field to be removed from the state which then allowed upgrading to terraform 0.13 possible without issue.

Unfortunately I do not understand how this worked and am guessing there is a change in TF 0.13 which causes an exception over removing the deprecated property since TF 0.12 was using the same version of the provider that 0.13 was using.

Answer (score 2):

This error is not related to your upgrade to Terraform 0.13, it is actually due to upgrading from version 2.x of the AWS Terraform provider to version 3.x. As stated in [the AWS Terraform provider 3.0 upgrade guide](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-3-upgrade#ses_smtp_password-attribute-removal) you need to switch from using `ses_smtp_password` to `ses_smtp_password_v4`.

The reason for this change is that SES will stop accepting the older type of password in October 2020, so you have to upgrade to the password that uses version 4 signatures before then.

As you've seen, you need to delete the old passwords from your Terraform state, and let Terraform generate new `ses_smtp_password_v4` passwords.

Comment: Github PR for the removal of the attribute: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/14299

Comment: @mark-b, I should have mentioned it, but I never created an ses_smtp_password at least that I knew of.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `azurerm` provider. It was pinned to version `~> 1.44` and suddenly after update to terraform 0.13, `unsupported attribute` errors started to appear.

What solved it for me (without the need to upgrade the provider):

1. Run `terraform 0.13upgrade` - this will create `versions.tf` with provider version contraints in the new format, i.e.:

   ```
   terraform {
       required_providers {
           azurerm = {
               source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
               version = "~> 1.44"
           }
       }
       required_version = ">= 0.13"
   }
   ```
2. Now, change `source = "hashicorp/azurerm"` to `source = "-/azurerm"`. This should make terraform use the old provider version.

For AWS provider, you should have something very similar, with different provider name and version.